# Solving system of equations where variables are matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

So I have a work sheet and the question was

"Solve the system of matrix equations for X and Y, that is, find X and Y matrices of size 4 x 3 satisfying the relations"

$$2X-Y = \begin{bmatrix}-12&-7&-4\\ -5&8&-7\\ 4&3&-1\\ 4&-6&-11\end{bmatrix}$$

And

$$X+3Y = \begin{bmatrix}40&25&16\\17&-27&24\\-15&-12&2\\-15&19&36\end{bmatrix}$$

So I don't quite understand what the want me to do I tried to solve the matrix using the Gaussian elimination but the system has no solution

Comment: You would notice that your matrices are unreadable as currently written.  Visit [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information on how to properly format mathematics here using MathJax and $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Suppose you are dealing with simultaneous equation:

$$2x-y=a$$

$$x+3y=b$$

where $a$ and $b$ are just real numbers, $x, y$ are in the real number as well. what would you have done to express $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

After you think through the above, then try to check can you do the same thing when you deal with matrices.

Comment: Well in this case I will just solve the system In one of the elements and when I get the value I will use it to get the other one But here I have a set of elements so I can't literally do it here!

Comment: which step doesn't work in matrices?

Comment: @TawTaw The exact same process works whether $x,y$ happen to be real numbers or matrices or whatever.  "*But here I have a set of elements so I can't literally do it here!*"  Yes, there are many entries within the matrix, however they appear in a very specific order!  You could try to find each individual entry in the matrices, for example let the first row first column entries of $X$ and $Y$ be called $x$ and $y$ respectively.  The conditions tell you when considering only the first row first column entries that $2x-y=-12$ and $x+3y=40$.  The rest can be found the same way...

Comment: @TawTaw  If you were to follow the hint and suggestions made here however, there is no need to go through twenty four different equations and twenty four different unknowns, you can treat the variables as matrices and go through simply two equations and two unknowns.  There is a solution and the difficulty should be no greater than if $x,y,a,b$ were all single real numbers.

Comment: yes that was useful I solved in 2 ways and finally got it